# Problem with inserting into a doubly linked list in ascending order

Tags: c++, sorting, doubly-linked-list

i need to make a function to sum 2 piecewise linear functions (both decreasing or increasing) and insert them into a third list in an ascending order based on the x-axis coordinates of each point. So i have created multiple functions, all seem to check out except this one yet i do not know what's the problem. It's not inputting anything at all.

struct **coords** has double x,y;
**dList** has : coords pt;
**node** has : node *head, *tail;
node *prev, *next;

```cpp
dList insert(dList L, coords point) {
  node *temp;
  temp = new node;
  if (temp == NULL) {
    cout << "error";
    exit(1);
  }
  temp->next = NULL;
  temp->prev = NULL;
  temp->pt = point;
  if (L.head == NULL || L.tail == NULL) {
    L.head = temp;
    L.tail = temp;
    return L;
  }
  if (L.head->pt.x > temp->pt.x) {
    temp->next = L.head;
    L.head->prev = temp;
    L.head = temp;
    return L;
  }
  if (L.tail->pt.x < temp->pt.x) {
    temp->prev = L.tail;
    L.tail->next = temp;
    L.tail = temp;
    return L;
  }
  node *cur;
  cur = L.head->next;
  while (cur->pt.x < temp->pt.x)
    cur = cur->next;
  temp->next = cur->next;
  temp->prev = cur;
  cur->next->prev = temp;
  cur->next = temp;
  return L;
}
```

Comment: Could you add how `node` and `dList` are defined? It doesn't add up. Looks like `node` has a `coords pt`, not the `dList` as you are telling us.

Comment: This is tagged C++ and you don't state any restrictions or reasons for them. So use `std::list` and forget all of the custom list hackery.

Comment: Also, what's this exact function, that you are asking about, supposed to do? Insert `coords` element into an existing list?

Comment: You have a problem on your insert. With the first node, you set `L.head=temp;` and `L.tail=temp;` (which is fine the list is just self-referencing, or circular at that point). The problem comes when you insert the second node. You are not handling the case where `L.head == L.tail` to know whether to set `L.head->next = L.tail = temp`. Instead for the second node you just compare the `point` for `head` and `tail` which are the same node at that time.

Answer (score 0):

The case in which the node to be inserted is in the middle is the problem. You should be looking one node ahead instead of looking at the current one. Try working it out on paper and you will see how that makes a difference:

```
  node * cur;
  // also start at head here
  cur=L.head;
  while(cur->next->pt.x<temp->pt.x)
    cur=cur->next;
  temp->next=cur->next;
  temp->prev=cur;
  cur->next->prev=temp;
  cur->next=temp;
```

You should also consider passing a dList L as a pointer to the function and also returning it as a pointer:

```
// this way you won't be making a copy of it, you may run into trouble if you don't have your copy constructor implemented
dList* insert(dList* L,coords point)
```

I hope that this helps you.

Comment: No problem. I am glad that I could help.